# About conditionals (future tense)

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I have been teaching conditionals to another student. I taught her the zero, first, second, and third conditional. We are not tackling mixed conditionals, and we were identifying which part of the sentence is second or third conditional. But I'm not sure which conditional the main clause is in this sentence: "If the weather is rainy, I am going to read a book at home". The if clause is first conditional, but what about the main clause?

Thank you!

Comment: The last sentence of your question is problematic since the so-called zero conditional also uses the present tense in the _if-clause_. It is better if your student understands that the numbered conditionals represent common conditional patterns, but that sentences with _if-clauses_ have numerous other combinations of verb constructions (usually called 'tenses' in traditional language teaching). In the sentence you are asking about, I think it is enough to say that it represents a hypothetical that is equivalent to the first conditional.

Comment: *Numbered* conditionals are a crude attempt to reflect how English works in respect of hypothetical scenarios. If you're not tackling "mixed conditionals" (wise choice, imho), there's no real point in trying to accurately classify your specific example (which is just colloquial / "loose" phrasing for ***If** [it rains,] I **will** read a book at home*).

Comment: 'I am going... etc' is not even a future tense. _'If the weather is rainy, I am reading a book at home'_ is the real concept. In absolute terms it means 'If weather rainy, I a book read.'

Comment: While you're obviously not learning English yourself, numbered conditionals are a didactic technique best handled on our sister site.

Comment: @Shoe Thank you! Your explanation really helps. I'll explain it like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The thing is...I am tackling "mixed conditionals"...it's a huge pain in the but. As for numbered conditionals and my sentence, I understand what you mean. Then I'll take a different approach.

Comment: @Nigel J I just noticed I misunderstood that..oops. That makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Got it! Thank you.

Comment: Please don't include "thanks!!!" in your post. Please see: [Expected Behavior](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)